# setting a Drawable background programmatically for a programmatically created button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I'm trying to set a drawable background to a button which is created programmatically.

Below is the code where I create the button and set the background

```
Button increaseQuantity = new Button(this);
increaseQuantity.setText("+");
//increaseQuantity.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.quantity_button);
increaseQuantity.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.quantity_button));
```

Below is the xml which has the code for the drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval" >
<stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#ee404040" />
<size android:width="2dp" android:height="2dp"/>
<gradient android:startColor="#11809100" android:centerColor="#11910000" android:endColor="#55FFB900" android:angle="45" />
</shape>
```

As per the xml my button should be in round shape (because width and height are the same), but I'm not able to get a round shaped button, instead I'm getting an oval shaped button. Could anyone correct this code to get a circular button?

Answer (score 0):

just two things here:

1. Replace the deprecated methods: `setBackgroundDrawable` and `getDrawable` are deprecated.
2. Set the dimensions programmatically

This should do the work:

```
increaseQuantity.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.round));
increaseQuantity.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100));
//replace 100 with your desired diameter of the button.
```

Also, you will have to replace `LinearLayout` to the parent layout you're associating your button with.

Comment: I'm using Tabular layout to place this button, will it work for tabular layout?

Comment: yeah, it should work. Just use `new TableLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100)` instead of `LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100)`